# Minimize delta between two lists

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

Given two lists where one is scaled by some factored `alpha`:

```
from random import randint

alpha = 1.2
x = [randint(1, 100) for x in range(1000)]
y = [int(alpha * i) for i in x]
```

I want to filter both lists for values under some threshold whereby the delta in the number of elements returned in both list is minimized. So if my threshold for `x` is 40 then `len([i for i in x if i < 40]) ~ 400` I want to know what the threshold value should be for `y` when `alpha` is unknown so the number of element return is ~ 400, *i.e. 48 for this example.*

Comment: If `alpha` is unknown, how would you even calculate `y`? If you want the same number of items in each list, the threshold for `y` is just `threshold * alpha`. Or filter `x` *then* create `y`.

Comment: I only set alpha for the question, I have two lists, one is an approximately scaled version of the other, I have a fixed threshold for x and I want the threshold for y. Obviously when you know the relationships between the lists the answer is clear.

Comment: So you have `x`, `y` and `x_threshold`, and you want to calculate `y_threshold`?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate an average `alpha` as:

```
alpha = sum((yn / float(xn)) for xn, yn in zip(x, y)) / len(x)
```

then:

```
y_threshold = int(alpha * x_threshold)
```

If minimising `abs(len(filtered_x) - len(filtered_y))` is crucial, you could then carry out a local search around `y_threshold`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x_threshold` allows you to know how many `x`'s are below it (here `400`). So you just need to find the element in `y` that ranks as the 400th and use it as `y_threshold`.

You do that by sorting `y` (which is overkill) or by selection of the Nth (can be done in`O(N)`). This approach always achieves `delta=0`.

For a simpler and approximate solution, estimate `alpha` as the ratio of the sums of both lists and set `y_threshold = alpha . x_threshold`. (The least-squares estimator of `alpha`, `Sum(y.x)/Sum(x^2)`, or the ratio of standard deviations, may be preferred)